# does every algebraic concept theoretically have an equivalent geometric concept?

Tags: education

I had a student ask what the relationship of algebra and geometry is.

does every algebraic concept theoretically have an equivalent geometric concept, even if it's impossible to draw/picture/visualize such as infinite dimensions?

for example, $x^n$ is the equivalent to 'volume' of the n-dimensional figure with dimensions whose length is $x.$

Comment: If you want a "yes or no" answer, then it is "no".

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean by a "concept".  The only example you've given is a single algebraic expression.  Are you asking whether every algebraic formula can be interpreted as some measurement of a geometric object?

Comment: yes, mweiss. That makes it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

For example can you graph the function defined by  $$f(x) =1 \text { if x is rational }$$ and $$f(x) =-1 \text { if x is irrational }$$

Could you graphically show that $$x^4-1= (x^2-1)(x^2+1)$$ or the binomial coefficient is $$ \frac {n!}{r!(n-r)!}?$$

Comment: doesn't that function look like a box (when you apply Lesbegue integration)? isn't the binomial coefficient just Pascal's Triangle?

Comment: The box or the Pascal triangle are  the oversimplification of deeper concepts. The box is not a geometrical box and the triangle is just a specific  arrangement of numbers in that form. Of course I am not downgrading  the importance of geometry in any way and I have used graphs in topology, discrete mathematics, real analysis and other subjects, but a graph is not a proof and does not work all the times.